# oAuth Token for Anonymous User in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth, anonymous

Team

Using Spring boot I am able to accomplish workflows, where oAuth server can generate the token for the logged-in user. However, how does the oAuth server generate a unique token for each anonymous user?

For e.g. if 2 concurrent users are trying to access the resource server from their respective browsers, then I would like the resource server to identify the 2 different users in each subsequent requests that they make. For that, I would like to generate different tokens for each  anonymous user. Is that possible and if yes then how?

Comment: need some clarification on question. Do you want to identify Anonymous user everytime?

Answer (score 1):

It is simple thing, you are making it complex.

> I would like to generate different tokens for each anonymous user. Is that possible

Once you generate valid token, user will become authenticated user.

You might think about validating token and setting `ROLE='ROLE_ANONYMOUS'`. As I told it will be like making simple thing to complex. Making authenticated user to Anonymous user is not good approach. You can create a new role like `ROLE_SEMIANONYMOUS` and grant authorities which were open for ANONYMOUS user.

(but this approach doesn't make any sense for me so explaining alternative to achieve your requirement of identifying AnonymousUser)

As "Anonymous User = UnAuthenticated User".

For anonymous user if you print principal

```java
String principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

principal = `"anonymousUser"`

You can create a session for anonymous user for identifying him as given below

```java
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();

if(principal instanceof String && ((String)principal).equalsIgnoreCase("anonymousUser"))
{
    if(request.getSession(false) == null)
    {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(300); // As per Your requirement
    //  store session id from session and ip address from request in to DB or cache if required and use it
    }
    else
    {
        //identify anonymous user against session id and stored details
    }
}
```

You can achieve this by registering a filter

- In convetional spring order of filter should be after springSecurityFilterChain.
- In spring boot you can achieve it by `FilterRegistrationBean`

Comment: Thanks, Praveen for your response. Do I need to persist a user with the role as "anonymousUser" in the AuthServer in this case? Is there any example on the net that I can check for reference.  Reason I'm asking this is because I am not able to test SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() in my controller because the request never reaches there unless I add the credentials of a user in the headers.

Comment: If you have not exposed any API for anonymous user then there is no chance of reaching request to controller. If you left some API's access to anonymous user then only you can, in those controller method you can test. Now your question in comments looks like you have fully secured your API's and trying to differentiate anonymous user. I am not  understanding this Will you explain your use case clearly so that you will get correct answer you are looking for.. May be someone will answer.

Comment: I have exposed an API which allows a user to add an item to cart. Now, this API is exposed to both a logged-in user as well as an anonymous user. The issue I'm facing is that although for the logged-in user I am able to get the Principal object using SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(). However, for the anonymous user, I am not sure if Spring Security out of the box provides an implementation or do I need to implement it myself?

Comment: If Spring security provides an out of the box solution, what is that and if I've to implement this functionality what is the best way to achieve this?